# Smooth scroll when click a map marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map where i display multiple markers and if a marker is clicked, you go to a div on the bottom of the page (classic anchor link)

Can someone tell me why i don't have smooth scroll when i click on marker, but i do have if i just create a link and a div with an ID?

This is the js:

```
  jQuery(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);

    // Multiple Markers
    var markers = [
        ['London Eye, London', 51.503454,-0.119562, '#1'],
        ['Palace of Westminster, London', 51.499633,-0.124755, '#2']
    ];



    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0],
            url: markers[i][3]
        });



       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
       window.location.hash = this.url;
    }); 
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var target = this.hash,
                    $target = $(target);

                    $('html, body').stop().animate({
                        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
                    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
                        window.location.hash = target;
                    });
                });
            });



        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(14);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess 'juping' is caused by this piece of code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
   window.location.hash = this.url;
});
```

Remove your event listeners:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
```

and this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
```

And add this piece of code which will get html tags by `marker.url` data and animate scrolling to them:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var elem = $(marker.url);
    $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: elem.offset().top
      }, 1000 );
});
```

It will smoothly scroll to your divs:

```
<div id='1'>1</div>
<div id='2'>2</div>
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o8u13whg/

### EDIT: Closure fix

The issue described in comment: *I've just noticed that now it will always scroll down to the last ID... no matter what marker you click.* is caused by [closures](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure) not being [handled properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), causing always **last** `marker.url` to be scrolled to.

To fix it, pull attaching the `click` event out of the `for` loop:

```
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0],
        url: markers[i][3]
    });
    attachClickHandler(marker);
    .....
```

and then inside `attachClickHandler(marker)` function do the scroll magic:

```
function attachClickHandler(marker){
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

     var elem = $(marker.url);
    $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: elem.offset().top
      }, 1000 );

});
}
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o8u13whg/3/

Closures can be a tricky thing :)

Comment: I've just noticed that now it will always scroll down to the last ID... no matter what marker you click.    
http://jsfiddle.net/o8u13whg/2/

Comment: @FlorinSimion: Sorry, see my edit in response. `Closures` are still a bit tricky concept for me :)

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy...  you saved my Friday  :)

Comment: I have heard that `let` keyword resolves the closure handling.
By that I mean `for(let  i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ )`